# No phone number record in django admin site

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-registration

Currently on my own django project at the admin site, I can only see username, email , first name, last name and staff status. The `UserCreationForm` I am using provided by django has a phone number text field that I included to let users key in their phone number, however, I cant seem to get the admin site to store the phone number record. Please tell me if there are any changes that should be made to my current code so that I can see the phone records.

Wondering if there is anything that I should be including to my admin.py or forms.py.

```
/* forms.py */
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from validate_email import validate_email


class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    phone_number = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email']

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data.get("email")
        if not validate_email(email, verify=True):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Invalid email")
        return email

/* views.py */
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm


def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            # do something with phone number??
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account created for {username}!')
            return redirect('blog-home')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})

/* admin.py */
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
```

I expect to see the phone number records in django's admin site.

Answer (score 0):

You do not appear to be saving your phone number to your database. You are merely collecting it.

1. I would recommend not using an `IntegerField` for storing phone numbers unless you know that they will all be from the same area code. The largest number an `IntegerField` can safely store is 214 748 3647. So it could only store phone numbers with area codes less than 214.
2. I assume that the phone number is being stored in your `User` model. You require something like this to replace your `# do something with phone number??` with something like this:

```
user = form.save()
user.refresh_from_db()
phone =form.cleaned_data.get('phone_number')
user.profile.phone_number = phone
user.save()
```

Comment: I've edited views.py according to the code you suggested, but still when I enter submit, it states attribute error profiles in user.profiles.phone_number = phone

Comment: What is your model for storing the phone number? You should use user.whateveryourmodelis.phone_number.

Comment: The default `user` has no place for a phone number.